# org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Failed to read server's response: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: java, xml-rpc

i want to make request from url to get values from the url, but when i hit the url shows erorr like in the title above. I'm using xlm-rpc interface to hit it, here is my code

```
String test="";
        Object[] result = null;
        Vector params = new Vector();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("label1", "value1"); 
        map.put("label2", "value2"); 
        map.put("label3", "value3"); 
        map.put("label4", "value4");
        map.put("label5", "value5");
        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>(map);
        params.addElement(map2);
        XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
        try 
        { 
            config.setServerURL(new URL("myurl")); 
            XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient(); 
            client.setConfig(config); 
            log.info("Client initialized: "+client);
            result = (Object[])client.execute("mymethod", params);
            log.info(result);
        } catch (MalformedURLException | XmlRpcException e) 
        { 
            log.info(e);
        }
```

how to input this ssl certificate in xml-rpc or is there another way how to do it? thank you

Comment: Sounds like a certificate issue. is your target url `https://.....`?

Comment: ya my target is https://... @Jens

Comment: So you have to add the certiificate of the remote Server to the keystore of the jvm

Comment: oh i see, i must asked for the certificate. How to add the certificate to my jvm? @Jens

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html